# how to change the database create_date after a restore?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2019, dmv

I just restored a database, but then I noticed the create_date remains from previous to the restore.

is there a way I can change the create_date to be as the new database (after the restore)?

this is the script:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [SUPT_S01_Radhe] 
FROM  DISK = N'\\krishna3.radhe.co.uk\support\MM_Backups\S01__JagannathaeCA_12122023.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'radhe_Data' TO N'Y:\DATA\SUPT_S01_radhe_shyam_Data.mdf',  
MOVE N'radhe_ChangeLog' TO N'W\:\DATA\SUPT_S01_radhe_shyam_ChangeLog.ndf',  
MOVE N'radhe_Docs' TO N'Z:\DATA\SUPT_S01_radhe_shyame_Docs.ndf',  
MOVE N'radhe_Log' TO N'P:\LOGS\SUPT_S01_radhe_shyam_Log.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1

select name, database_id, create_date from sys.databases d
where d.database_id in (1,2,3,4,8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says this about the create_date column:

> Date the database was created **or** renamed. [Emphasis mine.]

Rename your database, then rename it back, and you should get the create_date you want.

```
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe MODIFY NAME = SUPT_S01_Radhe_Copy;
GO  
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe_Copy SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

And then rename it back:

```
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe_Copy SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe_Copy MODIFY NAME = SUPT_S01_Radhe;
GO  
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Note: According to that same documentation, the create_date value does *not* change when a rename is performed on an Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

following the [answer by Doug Deden](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/334523/22336)

I did the alter database but I renamed the database to the same name,
and that changed the create_date without me having to be concerned about permissions.

the database in question is not involved neither in replication nor in availability group.

```
select * from sys.databases d with(nolock)
order by d.create_date desc

--before
--SUPT_S01_Radhe --2023-09-29 17:21:14.723

--after
--SUPT_S01_Radhe --2024-01-03 18:04:15.290


USE master;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe  SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe  MODIFY NAME = SUPT_S01_Radhe 
GO  
ALTER DATABASE SUPT_S01_Radhe  SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```